# STM32 and ESP8266EX Flash Programming

Tags: stm32, esp8266, programming, firmware

I'm a complete beginner to electronics, I have done few projects using different modules, it's so easy to do with modules. Now I want to learn and do some advanced hobby projects. So I decided to create a device with Nokia 5110 LCD display which shows date, time and latest news. For news, I have to connect with RestAPI and download the news to flash and show it on the screen every hour.  This time I wanted to create everything on my own without using any modules except LCD display. I'm creating a PCB with STM32L053 MCU and ESP8266EX SoC (JLCPCB Part # C77967). I created ESP8266EX schematic by referencing from ESP module and several schematic gathered from the internet. I'm confident about the schematics. But I have few doubts which needs to be cleared to proceed further.

1. Does ESP8266EX SoC comes with pre-intalled firmware or I have to install it manually?
2. If I have to install it manually means, Do I need to include USB to UART for ESP8266EX and separate USB to UART to STM32 in my PCB? If it has to be like that, then how can I connect Tx and Rx between STM32 and ESP8266EX?
3. If I wanted to include multiple MCUs in a project how should I program each MCU? Does it always needs RX and TX pinouts for each MCUs or can I use only one USB to UART for entire PCB board and route to all the MCUs with some kind of a switch?

I spent lot of time to google about the above questions, but unable to find a clear answer or guide. Everyone's explaining about modules but no one is explaining how to do for real world production device. Please suggest me some material to learn this.

I attached link below for ESP8266EX SoC:

JLCPCB: https://jlcpcb.com/parts/componentSearch?isSearch=true&searchTxt=ESP8266EX

Datasheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810101410_Espressif-Systems-ESP8266EX_C77967.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Definitely not if you buy the ESP8266EX as a separate IC (chip), not the built module with flash, etc. ESP8266 doesn't have any sort of internal programmable memory (i.e. flash). It always relies on external SPI flash for user code. Only built-in ROM it has is the UART bootloader which actually allows you to upload your code via UART (or USB with USB-UART converter) without the need of special hardware programmer (JTAG). The AT commands thing you've asked in comments are just one of the firmware (i.e. user code) for it. Some ready built modules are shipped with this firmware pre-programmed on SPI flash. But as you are building from scratch your SPI flash will be empty. Btw, make sure you've included one in your design. Without SPI flash the ESP8266EX are hardly of any use as it won't be able to execute anything (well, to be honest afair it can code from RAM and you can upload it there... but I doubt that's something you want).
2. Both ESP8266 and STM32L053 have more than 1 UART interfaces. You can use others from those that are used for UART programming for MCU-MCU communications. Or you can use other interface for MCU-MCU "talks". I2C, SPI, etc. You can even use WiFi of the ESP8266 for OTA (over the air, i.e. WiFi) updates for both MCUs (yet, flashing STM32 from ESP8266 requires some knowledge of programming protocol, you might lack atm). BTW STM32 are usually programmed with SWD interface with ST-Link/J-Link or any other sort of ARM DAP supported programmer/debugger.
3. That depends on your design. But yes, you can use one USB-UART for both MCUs if you include some sort of switch onboard.

Comment: Thanks for very brief answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Does ESP8266EX SoC comes with pre-intalled firmware or I have to install it manually?

The ESP8266 stores user programs in external SPI flash, you can count on that the SPI flash will be empty from factory. So you will need to flash it.

> If I have to install it manually means, Do I need to include USB to UART for ESP8266EX and separate USB to UART to STM32 in my PCB? If it has to be like that, then how can I connect Tx and Rx between STM32 and ESP8266EX?

Yes, you must be able to connect the programming UART to the PC to flash the device.
Although, the SoC has two UART interfaces, so if you want to use UART to communicate with STM32 the easiest solution is to use the other UART for that. Or use for example SPI to communicate with the STM32. Or you can implement some hardware-switch to select between programming or STM32.

> If I wanted to include multiple MCUs in a project how should I program each MCU? Does it always needs RX and TX pinouts for each MCUs or can I use only one USB to UART for entire PCB board and route to all the MCUs with some kind of a switch?

Sure you can. You could use some analog MUX for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here what user program means? As I have seen, I can communicate with ESP through AT commands. Does that core firmware stored in SoC or I have to manually store it in SPI flash? I thought user program means developer side program ex. Led blink.

Comment: @DeebashD ESP8266 is MCU itself, just like the STM32. Other architecture, peripherals, etc, but it's still has to be programmed. AT command is just one of the built firmware from the vendor. Still it's not built-in. ESP8266 doesn't have any sort of internal flash, so it always boots from external SPI flash. Be it AT commands firmware or your own code.